# Duplicating a handle and closing the original one afterwards

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing the following class:

```
class Handle
{
public:
    inline Handle()
    {
        handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    inline Handle(HANDLE handle)
    {
        this->handle = copyHandle(handle);
    }
    inline Handle(const Handle& rhs)
    {
        this->handle = copyHandle(rhs.handle);
    }
    inline bool isValid()
    {
        return handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    inline HANDLE getNativeHandle()
    {
        return copyHandle(this->handle);
    }
    inline void close()
    {
        if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }

    }
    inline virtual ~Handle()
    {
        if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            CloseHandle(handle);
    }
protected:
    HANDLE handle;
    HANDLE copyHandle(HANDLE copyable);
};
```

The .cpp file:

```
HANDLE Handle::copyHandle(HANDLE copyable)
{
    HANDLE ret;
    HANDLE current = GetCurrentProcess();
    if(copyable == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ret = copyable;

    else if(DuplicateHandle(current, copyable, current, &ret, 0, TRUE , DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS) == 0)
        {
            if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                throw SecurityException("The handle duplication was denied!");
            else
                throw InvalidHandleException("The handle could not be duplicated!");
        }

    return ret;
}
```

The class seems to work fine normally, but copying the handle, then closing the original handle and then copying the new handle will throw an exception or Windows Errorcode 6 which is "Invalid Handle Value".

At the moment, I think that closing the original handle leads to complete destruction of the copies too and makes me unable to use them afterwards.

```
Handle test = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
Handle copy = test;
test.close();
std::cout << copy.getNativeHandle() << std::endl; // throws an exception, but uses the same function as above
return 0;
```

Is there a possibility to duplicate the handle so it is not dependent on the existence of the original one?

Comment: Aside: `inline` is implied on member functions _defined_ inside a class body. You don't need to state it explictly, most programmers don't.

Comment: Two comments: you don't define a copy assignment operator so it is possible to copy your class without duplicating the contained handle, also, do you mean to copy the handle on `getNativeHandle`? This means that all clients of your class need to manually close the returned handle every time they retrieve it. It doesn't leave your class making life much easier for the client.

Comment: ...although I'm stuck on what is actually causing the error you are getting. It looks like it should be OK for the use case that you are using.

Comment: Your test code is broken, test.close() doesn't compile.  Couldn't get a repro when I fixed it.  Copying the handle in the constructors is a questionable practice, apt to cause leaks.  Be sure to assert the return value of CloseHandle().

Comment: I also thought about the problem of having to close the handle manually, but generally, I try to avoid using native handles and use my handle class instead. getNativeHandle is for cases where the class is not able to solve my problem. @Hans Passant How would you do it then? When the original handle is closed, the object is broken if it doesn't have a copy.

Comment: @jgpt: How do you do anything with the contained handle without duplicating it? Such as pass to `WaitForSingleObject` or something similar?

Comment: @Charles Bailey In which case do I not copy it? My constructors call copyHandle() which calls DuplicateHandle().

Comment: I changed the codesnippet, I accidentally didn't check the code I pasted again and then posted it with "HANDLE" instead of "Handle". Sorry for that.

Comment: @jgpt: You have not defined a copy assignment operator so the compiler will generate one for you that just does a straight assignment of `handle`.

Comment: @jgpt: For now, I would recommend putting some basic logging in `copyHandle` so you can see each successful copy attempt as well.

Comment: Oh, I thought Handle(const Handle& rhs) is the copy constructor... I didn't write anything in c++ for months, so I seem to have mixed those things up. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from leaking a handle, this totally works on my machine.

Comment: It also works for me now. Thanks to everyone for solving the problem!

Comment: @jgpt: No, not the _copy constructor_, the _copy assignment operator_.

Comment: Voting to close as there's no problem to solve here.

Comment: Ah, ok, unfortunately, my C++ reference didn't mention the difference.

Comment: C++ and the Windows API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288076.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this implementation:

```
class Handle
{
public:
    Handle(HANDLE ahandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        handle = ahandle; // <- take ownership of the original, not a copy
    }

    Handle(const Handle& src)     
    {
        handle = src.duplicate(); // <-- take ownership of a copy
    }

    ~Handle()
    {
        close();
    }

    void close()
    {
        if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }

    HANDLE getNativeHandle() const
    {
        return handle;
    }

    bool isValid() const
    {
        return (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    }

    HANDLE duplicate()
    {
        if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return handle;

        HANDLE ret, current = GetCurrentProcess();
        if (!DuplicateHandle(current, handle, current, &ret, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                throw SecurityException("The handle duplication was denied!");
            else
                throw InvalidHandleException("The handle could not be duplicated!");
        }

        return ret;
    }

    Handle& operator=(HANDLE &rhs)
    {
        close();
        handle = rhs; // <-- take ownership of the original, not a copy
        return *this;
    }

    Handle& operator=(const Handle &rhs)
    {
        close();
        handle = rhs.duplicate(); // <-- take ownership of a copy
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    HANDLE handle;
};
```

On a side note, some API functions use `NULL` instead of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and some do not use `CloseHandle()`. You should consider accounting for those differences.  I would suggest updating the `Handle` class to use C++ templates so you can specialize the behavior on a per-instance basis, eg:

```
struct InvalidHandleTrait
{
    static const HANDLE InvalidValue = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
};

struct NullHandleTrait
{
    static const HANDLE InvalidValue = NULL;
};

struct CloseHandleTrait
{
    static bool close(HANDLE handle)
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
};

template< typename HandleTrait = InvalidHandleTrait, typename CloseTrait = CloseHandleTrait >
class Handle
{
public:
    Handle(HANDLE ahandle = HandleTrait::InvalidValue)
    {
        handle = ahandle; // <- take ownership of the original, not a copy
    }

    Handle(const Handle& src)     
    {
        handle = src.duplicate(); // <-- take ownership of a copy
    }

    ~Handle()
    {
        close();
    }

    void close()
    {
        if (handle != HandleTrait::InvalidValue)
        {
            CloseTrait::close(handle);
            handle = HandleTrait::InvalidValue;
        }
    }

    HANDLE getNativeHandle() const
    {
        return handle;
    }

    bool isValid() const
    {
        return (handle != HandleTrait::InvalidValue);
    }

    HANDLE duplicate()
    {
        if (handle == HandleTrait::InvalidValue)
            return handle;

        HANDLE ret, current = GetCurrentProcess();
        if (!DuplicateHandle(current, handle, current, &ret, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                throw SecurityException("The handle duplication was denied!");
            else
                throw InvalidHandleException("The handle could not be duplicated!");
        }

        return ret;
    }

    Handle& operator=(HANDLE &rhs)
    {
        close();
        handle = rhs; // <-- take ownership of the original, not a copy
        return *this;
    }

    Handle& operator=(const Handle &rhs)
    {
        close();
        handle = rhs.duplicate(); // <-- take ownership of a copy
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    HANDLE handle;
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between a Handle from GetCurrentProcess and a standard invalid handle?

Comment: Do you mean `DuplicateHandle()` instead of `GetCurrentProcess()`? `GetCurrentProcess()` returns a pseudo handle. AFAIK, there is no way to query a handle to know if it was duplicated or not. Either way, both types of handles will not be set to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define an assignment operator for `Handle`. I suspect the code that actually crashed looked like this:

```
Handle test = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
Handle copy;
copy= test; // assigned instead of using copy constructor
test.close();
std::cout << copy.getNativeHandle() << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Without an assignment operator, you do not duplicate the handle properly.

Comment: I have now added:        `        Handle & operator= (const Handle& other)
        {
            this->close();
            this->handle = copyHandle(other.handle);
            return *this;
        }`